# need to create a new column that pulls data from another column, uses a variable for a date range and returns a value based on the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a new column and the data for that column is based on a date or date range that is from another column labeled (Sys_Created) in the same Database. it needs to return a value of "New" or "Existing" in this new column labeled "Cust_Status

I'd like to also return this value also if we have received an order or payment in the last 6 months. this would re-establish this "Existing" customer as a "New" customer.

--This is my current code: the purpose of this query is to report the sales of all customers that were created as a customer or a lead in 2017. this will soon expand to all date ranges, but for the sake of speed, I just did 1 year.

```
`declare @startdate datetime = '1/1/2017'
declare @enddate datetime = '12/20/2017'

SELECT C.cmp_name, 
       C.debcode,
       C.statecode as State,
       c.cmp_fcity as City,
       c.ClassificationId,
       c.SalesPersonNumber as SalesPerson,
       Max(C.type_since)AS TypeSince, 
       Max(C.syscreated)AS SysCreated, 
       Max(C.cmp_status)AS CmpStatus, 
       SUM(( 1 - L.discount_pct / 100 ) * L.qty_ordered * L.unit_price * 
L.uom_ratio *  
(  CASE WHEN L.ord_type = 'C' THEN -1  ELSE 1      END )) as TotDollars


FROM  cicmpy AS C 
       LEFT JOIN oehdrhst_sql AS H 
              ON C.debcode = h.cus_no 
       LEFT JOIN oelinhst_sql AS L 
              ON H.ord_no = L.ord_no 
                 AND H.ord_type = L.ord_type 

WHERE  C.cmp_type = 'C' 
       AND L.sls_amt > '0.00'  
       AND C.type_since >= @startdate 
       AND C.type_since <= @enddate 
GROUP  BY C.cmp_name, 
          C.debcode,C.statecode,c.cmp_fcity,c.ClassificationId, 
c.SalesPersonNumber`
```

Comment: You have to at least show what you already have. Any code, any researches...

Comment: Please post a description of the tables involved. Also clarify whether you need this field created as part of the table, or just as part of a query.

Comment: edited the content to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Add column to existing table
alter customers
add cust_ctatus int

-- set status "1" if any payments in last 6 mo
-- I assume you have a column with last payment date. You can use data from other table instead.
update customers
set cust_ctatus = 1
where month(getdate)-month(payment_date)<7
```

Note: You have not enough description. Thus, the peace above is just to give direction, not the final answer. I might modify my answer when a better description is given.